# How to hide a column in a lazy grid?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazyvgrid

I want to represent a train seats inside a LazyVerticalGrid but the centre column should always be invisible

here is my code

```
  LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(spanSize),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .run {
                    padding(start = 24.dp, top = 50.dp, end = 24.dp, bottom = 40.dp)
                        .background(Color(0xFFE6F1F3), RoundedCornerShape(78.dp))
                },

        ){
             items(
                count = seatHoldersList.size,
             )  {

                 if(!seatHoldersList[it].isSpace && !seatHoldersList[it].isBreak &&!seatHoldersList[it].centerBreak)

                SeatCell(seatNumber = seatHoldersList[it].displayNumber)
            }
        }
    }
```

[here is the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or32y.jpg)

Comment: If you know the indices of the items you want to hide, you can just not render those positions.